# content_tag concatenation clean up

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails

I need to concatenate two content_tag and it works but it seems a little messy to me. Any thoughts on how may I refactor this?

```
def format_price(money)
  mny = get_price_string(money).to_money
  str = content_tag(:span, @visitor.currency.symbol.html_safe, class: 'pounds')
  str << mny.format(no_cents: true, symbol: '')
  str << content_tag(:span, mny.format[-3, 3], class: 'pence') unless condition?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes:

- Before refactoring, let's identify what makes this code feel "messy". IMO there are two problems: the in-place method `<<` and the inline statement `unless`. As usual, I'll try to make the case for functional programming (as opposed to imperative programming, not opposed to OOP). I guess you are not familiar with [FP in Ruby](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming) but somehow you felt something was wrong. A quick intro: when you update variables in-place, the `=` symbol loses a lot of its glamour :-) In maths `x = "hello"` means that, in this scope, `x` is always equal to 'hello'. Period. In imperative programming it means "for now `x` is equal to 'hello', but I reserve the right to change it whenever I feel like it, in this scope or any other. Good luck debugging!". I don't know about you, but I prefer `=` to mean the first one :-) Yes, even for a such simple and short code.
- I don't understand: `m.format`, where is `m`? is it `mny`?
- `ebeach?`. What is `ebeach?`?
- `m.format[-3, 3]`. Do you want the last 3 chars of a string? In Rails: `m.last(3)`.
- `@visitor`: Using an instance variable in a helper is a no-no. Pass it as an argument.

So let's rewrite the snippet in functional style. There are at least two ways, 1) use different variable names for the different values and concat the strings, or 2) use an array+compact+join. The first:

```
def format_price(money_value, visitor)
  money = get_price_string(money_value).to_money
  symbol = content_tag(:span, visitor.currency.symbol.html_safe, class: 'pounds')
  value = money.format(no_cents: true, symbol: '')
  currency = ebeach? ? "" : content_tag(:span, money.format.last(3), class: 'pence')
  symbol + value + currency
end
```

Note how pure functions in FP follow a simple pattern: create intermediate variables (if needed, to make the method more readable and declarative) and use them in the last expression of the method. Don't "do things", declare "what things are".

Second approach:

```
def format_price(money_value, visitor)
  money = get_price_string(money_value).to_money
  [
    content_tag(:span, visitor.currency.symbol.html_safe, class: 'pounds'),
    money.format(no_cents: true, symbol: ''),
    *(content_tag(:span, money.format.last(3), class: 'pence') if condition?),
  ].join
end
```

Of course an alternative approach would have been to create a partial view instead of rendering from a helper.

Comment: First, thanks for answering. I am totally aware of the advantages of immutability and functional approach. The main problem with that... is me, since it's still unfamiliar to me. So let's give it a try.
**1** yes, I've just updated the question **2** some conditional helper **3** is it better? **4** yes you're right
It still seems very procedural to me though, even if assigning everything to a new variable

Comment: "it still seems very procedural". There is this misunderstanding with FP on this regard, as if it had to avoid intermediate variables, everything being  chains of expressions (the more point-free, the better). But that's not the case (even though it's idiomatic to do this kind of things in FP languages, for example Haskell). The key aspect of FP is -as you say- immutability. I'll add the second solution to see how to do without so many variables. But none of these two are procedural (where the key point is do calculations by changing the state).

Comment: It's ok to me, will you just explain to me the * before the conditional content tag?

Comment: It's the shortest (and probably most idiomatic) way of flattening the array (here, remove the `nil`, equivalent to `[]` when flattening). I am not a big fan of this syntax (I usually use `compact`, with `flatten(1)` when needed). Do some tests in a console and you'll see.